# Is it possible to use a locator for a webpage in an app that uses a webview?

Tags: selenium, appium, android-webview

I need to develop regression test automation for the app that switches to webview using selenium, appium.

Can the locator used in the web page be used as it is in the app web view environment?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the views are built for the web and app.
There was a time we were able to use the same selectors for both web E2E and App with the same screens rendered in webview.

Comment: thank you I'll have to talk to the developer! :)